# Excel: Split strings into duplicate rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

The attached screenshot explains best what I need.
What I have now are rows of customers and each customer might have multiple email addresses in one cell. I need to duplicate the customer rows for each email they have so that each row will only have one email per customer.

I know I can whip up some VBA code for this but I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish this without VBA. "Text to Columns" didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by converting the data into a table and then using a Power Query to split the data and using a Line Feed for the delimiter.